# Data wrangling: Sum values from two different arrays in javascript and push a new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-wrangling

I have two arrays/json files in the following format:

```
  const data2 = [{date: "2018-04-23", a: 2, b: 2},
   {date: "2020-04-24", a: 1, b: 2},
   {date: "2020-04-25", a: 1, b: 2}]
  
  const data3 = [{date: "2018-04-23", a: 5, b: 2},
   {date: "2020-04-24", a: 4, b: 2},
   {date: "2020-04-25", a: 1, b: 2}]
```

and I want to get the following result:

```
  const result = [{date: "2018-04-23", sum: 7},
   {date: "2020-04-24", sum: 5},
   {date: "2020-04-25", sum: 2}]
```

what is the best way to calculate/create this new array?

I have tried this:

```
  let result = [];

  for( var i=1; i < data3.length; i++) {
    result.push({ date: data3[i].date,
                  sum: data2[i].a + data3[i].a})   
  }
```

The issue is that I need to make sure that both `data2` and `data3` arrays are sorted by `date`. Is there a better way to do it accounting for the `date` in the for loop? Any other structure different to a for loop is fine. I would like to know what is the best way to obtain the `result` array checking by `date`.

Comment: what is the value `sum`?

Comment: the sum of `a` in `data2` and `a` in `data3`

Comment: it doesn't match the expected output then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const result = data2.map(item => {
    const fItem = data3.find(e=>e.date === item.date)
    if(fItem){
        return {date: item.date, sum: item.a + fItem.a}
    }
    return {date: item.date, sum: item.a}
})
```

I hope this code will useful for you

And I have the other solution is to convert data3 as an object with keys are date and values are an attribute. For example:

```
const object = data3.reduce((init, item)=> ({...init, [item.date]: item.a}), {})
```

After that use is the same above

```
    const fItem = data3.find(e=>e.date === item.date)
```

change to

```
    const fItem = obj[item.date]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create map and then sum the values

```js
const data2 = [{
    date: "2018-04-23",
    a: 2,
    b: 2
  },
  {
    date: "2020-04-24",
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  },
  {
    date: "2020-04-25",
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  }
]

const data3 = [{
    date: "2018-04-23",
    a: 5,
    b: 2
  },
  {
    date: "2020-04-24",
    a: 4,
    b: 2
  },
  {
    date: "2020-04-25",
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  }
]

const map2 = data2.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.date] = cur.a;
  return acc;
}, {});
const map3 = data3.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.date] = (acc[cur.date] || 0) + cur.a;
  return acc;
}, map2);
const result = Object.keys(map3).map(k => {
  return {
    date: k,
    sum: map3[k]
  };
});


console.log(result);
```